# Logging into PHPMYADMIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

My website runs off of an AWS server. I went to login to phpmyadmin and placed in the username and password that matches the username and password in `config.inc.php` and I get the error:

> The user name or password you entered for this area on ___________:80 was incorrect

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: To be more specific, I know the password in the config.inc.php is the password to my database on AWS RDS BUT I don't recall the username and password for the website/phpmyadmin.... tips?

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin doesn't have user accounts, when you enter your credentials in the login field those are passed on directly to MySQL ([more information](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#a-word-about-users)).

The only time you should need to have your username and password in `config.inc.php` is if you're using the "config" [auth_type](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-authentication-modes), in which case you aren't prompted at all when logging in.

But the thing is, that doesn't sound like a phpMyAdmin error message. Perhaps you have some other means in place of protecting your phpMyAdmin installation, such as a .htaccess file or Apache configuration directives.

I suggest starting with the command line client, see if you can log in with the username and password you have. Next, look at the phpMyAdmin configuration, `config.inc.php`, and for testing purposes I suggest you use auth_type cookie. That way, if you get a popup login dialog you know something else is restricting you. With auth_type cookie, phpMyAdmin displays the username and password fields on a web page form rather than a popup dialog. Finally, check your webserver error log for any hints; it might log more information about where this authentication is configured.